# Building multilayer perceptron Neural Network

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, neural-networks

I’m new to machine learning and am a bit confused about how to create a neural network (multilayer perceptron) with a specific design.

I would like to create a neural network with 40 features/neurones in input layer, 2 hidden layers each with 200 neurones and sigmoid activation function then one neurone in output layer to predict a scalar.

Should I use NetChain and then have the layers:

```
LinearLayer[{40,200}],ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid],LinearLayer[{200,200}], ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid],LinearLayer[{200,1}]
```

In order to produce the network I have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[200], ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid], 
   LinearLayer[200], ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid], 
   LinearLayer[1]}, "Input" -> 40, "Output" -> NetDecoder["Scalar"]]

Information[net, "SummaryGraphic"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can also be produced more concisely:

```
net = NetChain[{200, LogisticSigmoid, 200, LogisticSigmoid, 1}, 
  "Input" -> 40, "Output" -> NetDecoder["Scalar"]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain please why we need a 3rd linear layer and activation layer? Why after the two hidden layers can we not go directly to an output neuron/layer?

Comment: I have edited the question and removed the last activation layer. You don't need it unless you want to force your output to the $[0,1]$ range. You do, however, need the last layer (imagine it as being the "output" layer) so that you get from 400 nodes to a scalar output.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation.

Comment: When I use this net code, I get an error when I go to train it - output is not a scalar (which I want it to be) but a 9000-element array. My trainingdata set has 9000 elements which are of the form {-4.007, 0.3698, -1., -0.1528, -0.5851, 
  0.4517, -0.1968, -0.1535, 0.076, 
  0.2107, -0.32301, -0.3082, 1., 0.2733, 0.5368, -0.31, 
  0.01269, 0.298, -0.3772, -0.3255, 0.223, 
  0.2298, -0.683, 0.0712, -0.87, 0.4012, -0.324, 
  0.3523, 0.8496, 0.084, -0.007, 0.6469, -0.222, 
  0.8281, -0.4817, 0.282618, 
  0.0196, -0.1807, -0.246, -0.1187} -> 0.267              . What could this be?

Comment: As you can see in the SummaryGraphic, the output is supposed to be a vector with size 1. So your data should look like ``{x1, x2, ..., x40} -> {y1}``. However, the other solution is to explicitly specify that you want the output to be a scalar: ``NetChain[{200, LogisticSigmoid, 200, LogisticSigmoid, 1}, "Input" -> 1, "Output" -> NetDecoder["Scalar"]]``. I hope either of these two solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you - I will give those a try now.  When I tried to create the SummaryGraphic nothing actually appeared like it did not recognise the command which is odd.

Comment: Bit off topic but I am also thinking of getting a new laptop to help with this neural network project I’m doing - my current laptop is over 10yrs old. Do you think the M1 macs are any good for these sorts of tasks? They come with 8 or 16GB of RAM.